# How do I get more than 50 associated work items for a VSTS build?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I’m trying to use the VSTS Build (2.0) API to retrieve the associated work items and changes for a given build.
This build has 100 work items associated with it.
When I use the get build details/work items REST method, it will only retrieve 50 items. I’ve tried the following:
https://my-account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_apis/build/builds/7/workitems?api-version=2.0 // Without specifying a maximum number of work items -> it returns 50
https://my-account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_apis/build/builds/7/workitems?api-version=2.0&$top=100 // specifying a maximum of 100 items -> it returns 50
https://my-account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_apis/build/builds/7/workitems?api-version=2.0&$top=0 // specifying a top of 0, hoping that means all -> it returns none
https://my-account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_apis/build/builds/7/workitems?api-version=2.0&$top=-1 // specifying a top of -1, hoping that means all -> it returns none
https://my-account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_apis/build/builds/7/workitems?api-version=2.0&$top=50&$skip=50 // hoping to get the next 50 items (51..100) -> it returns the same first 50

Any idea how I can get the complete list of associated work items? And associated changes, for that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this through a single Rest API(https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#work-items) for now.

I had a similar experience and finally found this issue: [TFS 2017 Update1: Associated Work Items for a build has a limit of 50 work items](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/38322/tfs-2017-update1-associated-work-items-for-a-build.html). However the issue still **Under Consideration** without any udpate.

Eventually, as a workaround, I get all related changesets for a single build and  **retrieve all related work items for each changesets.**

Perform effectively but not efficiently.

Comment: @Assaf Stone Tomhans's is right, that's an known issue, first reported in [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1dda2298-b88d-49ee-a586-375bb42d07fa/associated-work-items-for-a-build-has-a-limit-of-50-work-items?forum=tfsgeneral). You can try to retrieve the associated work items from the changesets.

Comment: Thanks Tomhan and Andy. I couldn't find the API for retrieving the work items for a changeset. Could you point me at the API?

Comment: @AssafStone Get the changeset ID first from the build. Then use below REST API : `http://your-account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets/{ID}/workItem`

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, for TFVC. For Git, I had to parse the comment for instances work item IDs. I used the following expression: [Regex]::Matches($change.comment, '#(?<id>\d+)') | Select-Object @{ Name = "Value"; Expression = {$_.Groups['id'].Value
}}