# What is the max number of work items returned from this Azure Devops API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the API listed here: [Get Work Items between Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20work%20items%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#resourceref) to make an inhouse product that lets us quickly build release notes for each version of our product.  But I seem to get a total return value of 50 often.  And we are now noticing that some results are left off.  Is 50 the limit that this API returns?  I dont see any indications of this on the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/48677533/7146596?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get more than 50 associated work items for a VSTS build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674968/how-do-i-get-more-than-50-associated-work-items-for-a-vsts-build)

Comment: No, for multiple reasons.  The answer that you have provided is trying to get all work items from One build, I need all the work items between two builds.  The other issue being that I cant use the workaround provided because I dont have access to every build in between the two builds.  We are retaining only the first and last build of a sprint.

Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve more work items use the `$top` filter in rest api [Get Work Items between Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20work%20items%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1).

For below example in powershell script:

```
# special character `$` in `$top` needs to be escaped.
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/ORG/PROJ/_apis/build/workitems?fromBuildId=8913&toBuildId=8917&`$top=200&api-version=6.1-preview.2"

$PAT="....."
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method get

$result.count
```

Note: You need to escape the special character `$` in `$top` filter by adding a back tick "'".

See below result from my test. I can got all the related work items.
[image]

Comment: I will try this and let you know if it works.

Comment: This absolutely is the case, apparently there is an implicit `$top` of 50, if you pass in more it will return a higher limit.